# prevention of scroll reset when linking?

Tags: html, css

First time overflowing the stack.

I'm making a website with several html pages that are identical except for the fact that they contain different images that are more or less identical in size - and thats how they are named, by the jpg that they feature.

The pictures look great with the website, but I have a 300 pixel header that pushes them downward > forcing you to scroll down to see the full image. This is built into the shared CSS for all these gallery pages.

I have simple text links below the images that are hard coded to point to the next image in the gallery. (I have a list of the 20 images im displaying). When someone clicks the image, it goes to that page and resets the scroll to the top, which makes the header push the image area down.

Can anyone tell me how to prevent the scroll reset behavior of the new link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without using something like jQuery, you could link the pages such that you have an anchor tag like `<a name="gallery"></a>` above the images on each page and when giving the link to the various pages, append a `#gallery` to the url such as `<a href="next_image.html#gallery">Next Image</a>`. This is duplicated on each page however, and will not produce a robust webpage. You'll want to change things in the future and this will cause problems and further work, so I  would consider a dynamic alternative.

Note this won't look as seamless as with jQuery and using AJAX to load in the images when needed. Or better yet, as most JS galleries work, load the images into the page invisible at first and then with JS have them show up on the link click. The benefit of this would be that you could generate the links in JS using the provided images. If the images are large enough that they may cause considerable lag on page load, consider making placeholder images of some sort. In any case, take a look at [lightbox 2](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/).

Also, I didn't get the feeling you were using any server side scripting to create this gallery. If the js solution doesn't suit you or you find the added benefit of generating part of the website automatically based on the content need at the time, take a look at using something like PHP, Python, Ruby, etc. If it's just a simple website you're after, a great solution might be [Wordpress](http://wordpress.org/).

Comment: Yea, I added an anchor and the scrolling stopped. Very solid, thanks. I am displaying 400kb images so the load time isn't too much of a concern at this point given my needs.  Eventually I'll create a more efficient website gallery when I am able to grasp the server side scripting. At this point I'm looking to build things brick by brick, but homegrown. I have a graphic design background so I'm able to disguise its simplicity via graphics.

Answer (score 0):

You could have one page and just replace the images?
http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/fir.html

Now of course you change the function to work on a "previous/next" button system, assuming you have a photo gallery of some sort.

Please post more details.

Answer (score 0):

You want your link to look something like this:

```
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com/html_links.htm#tips">
Visit the Useful Tips Section</a>
```

and you want to give your image an id="tips" in this case.

Check out this fiddle to see an example.  The only difference is that your href will have the rest of the url in there like the code posted above.

http://jsfiddle.net/QgzsL/